# How to create table and design relationship for this article

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have tour service on my app, each tour has many "required documents", "rules", "services" and ..., how do i create a table to connect each tour to it's own options!? by the way i don't want to create pivot table for each option.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least one pivot table, like 'tour_details'. In this table you'll hold the 'tour_id', containing the id of the tour, 'type', containing the type of the detail (rules, services, etc) and the 'detail_id', containing the id of the the type you defined previously.

For example:

Table '**tour**':

```
    Schema::create('tour', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        other table columns you need...
    });
```

Table '**tour_details**':

```
    Schema::create('tour', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tour_id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('detail_id');

        $table->foreign('tour_id')->references('id')->on('tours');
    });
```

Here, the detail_id references the ID of the type you choose. Eg.: type = 'rules' and detail_id = '21' mean it's the id 21 of the table rules.

Without more info we can't help you very much, but I hope this info was useful enough to put you on track.

Comment: thank you very much, there is another question. how can i define the relationships in eloquent  model to  retrieve details?